# Error when getting first item with .parent().find('img').eq(0)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to capture an 'img' inside an 'a' tag, but cannot achive unfortunatelly. Below is my html:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Category Name</td>
            <td>Status</td>
            <td>Display Rank</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>            
        @foreach (var category in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 200px">
                    <span style="cursor: pointer">@category.Name</span>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 200px">
                    <div id="@category.ID">
                        @if (category.Status == 1)
                        {
                            <img src="~/img/ok-icon.png" />
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="make-passive"><img val="@category.ID"  src="~/img/Alarm-Error-icon.png" /></a>
                        }
                        else if (category.Status == 0)
                        {
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="make-active">
                                <img val="@category.ID" src="~/img/Alarm-Tick-icon.png" />
                            </a>
                            <img src="~/img/Close-icon.png" />
                        }
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 160px">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="take-up">
                        <img src="~/img/Arrows-Up-4-icon.png" />
                    </a><br />
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="take-down">
                        <img src="~/img/Arrows-Down-4-icon.png" />
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And, this is my JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click', 'a.make-passive', function () {
    var imgPassive = $(this).parent().find('img').eq(0);
    var imgNo = imgPassive.attr('val');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "@Url.Action("DeactivateCategory", "Admin")/" + imgNo,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.Name + "has been successfully removed among active categories.");
            $('#' + imgNo).html("trial by sword");
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert(data.Name + "cannot be removed among the other categories. An error occured.");
        }
    });
});
```

By placing debuggers, i realized that the problem comes from `var imgPassive = $(this).parent().find('img').eq(0);`

I successfully used `.parent().find()` methods on several other pages, but cannot see what makes it not work on this page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `var imgPassive = $(this).closest('div').find('img').eq(0);`

Comment: @RaZzLe You don't need `$(this).parent().find('img').eq(0);` since the img is inside the clicked element. You can simply do `$(this).find('img');`

Comment: @RaZzLe what error you got in console.

Comment: This  `$(this).closest('div').find('img').eq(0)` would resolve in finding this `<img src="~/img/ok-icon.png" />` And as you can see it does not have a value.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen yep i know, but i just want to catch Alarm-Error-icon which has a value

Comment: @RaZzLe Try use `$(this).find('img').eq(0)`

Comment: @KiranShahi i got 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: By the way, `$(this).closest('div').find('img').eq(0);` doesnt work but `$(this).find('img').eq(0)` works. Still cannot figure out the difference very well. Kiran said 'since the img is inside the clicked element' but doesnt this make that 'img' and 'a' a parent?

Comment: @RaZzLe are there multiple image ?

Comment: The problem with `$(this).parent().find("img")[0]` is that it will find the first image under the parent.  If you have two (or more) `a img` then it will always give the first, not the one you've clicked on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `$(this).parent().find('img').eq(0);` since the `img` you want to get is inside the clicked element. You can simply do `$(this).find('img').eq(0);`